# Difference between SetupSuite & SetupTest in Testify Suites

Tags: go, testify

I am trying to figure out difference between `SetupSuite` and `SetupTest` for quite some time now. Based on information on blogs I have understood that `SetupSuite` is run before entire suite and `SetupTest` runs before each test case. But what could be practical example in such a case? And how does dependency injection differ in both the cases?

Comment: Just as you said--one runs before the entire suite of tests, the other before an individual test. I'm not sure what further clarification is possible or desired.

Comment: Any practical example where anyone is preferred over other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally you want to use `SetupTest` so that each individual test function runs with a clean environment. `SetupSuite` is useful in cases where the setup code is time consuming and isn't modified in any of the tests. An example of when this could be useful is if you were testing code that reads from a database, and all the tests used the same data and only ran `SELECT` statements. In this scenario, `SetupSuite` could be used once to load the database with data.